# DNS server does not respond after reboot in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, dns, ethernet

First of all, I think that this might be an issue with the router (TP-Link) because I never had this problem before I moved into a new apartment. But I also recently formatted my PC, so I'm not sure where the problem is.

The problem is, I set my adapter (ethernet cable) to use OpenDNS, it works fine. But when I restart the computer, there is no internet connection, and it says `"DNS Server does not respond"`

So every time I restart to computer, I have to switch to automatic DNS, then switch back to OpenDNS.

What is the problem here, and how can I solve it so that I only use OpenDNS, without changing it every time ? I can provide details like exact router version, or output of some cmd commands.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The reason which I most likely see with your computer is may be your DNS service is corrupted on the PC. The following should resolve your problem.

1. Open an Administrator Command Prompt and type the following :- `ipconfig /flushdns` .

If this doesn't work then proceed with the following steps :-

2. Type `netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt` in the Administrator command prompt.
3. Type `netsh winsock reset` in the command prompt. It will prompt for a restart but do not do it.
4. Again Type `ipconfig /flushdns` in the command prompt.

Also, ensure that the DNS settings are properly configured inside the router as well. Furthermore rather than trying to use the OpenDNS DNS servers, try using Google DNS Servers as well which are : - `8.8.8.8` & `8.8.4.4` .

One more thing to make sure is that your DNS client service is turned on. To check this, open a `RUN prompt` by pressing `WINDOWS KEY + R` and type in `services.msc` and press `ENTER`. Now find the service called `DNS CLIENT` and check if it is started or not. Also right click on the service, select `Properties` and make sure that the `Startup Type` is set to `Automatic`.

Now, if the `flushdns` trick works and you would like to do it on every startup, make a BAT file with the command `ipconfig /flushdns` and place it in the `Startup` folder.

I hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem also happens with Google DNS. So let me try your methods.

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw - So did the problem get resolved?

Comment: Nope. I tried flushdns both before and after reboot. I still have to go to network adapter settings, and disable and enable back the Local Area Connection to connect to the Internet. **edit**: in the services, DNS Service is working and automatically starting up.

Comment: Can you try connecting with some other router as well and see if the issue persists? Incase you don't have any other router, do you have a spare Windows laptop or a decent smartphone? If yes, then setup a Wifi-Hotspot and try connecting to that using your default setup. Let me know the results of the analysis.

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw - Try this one as well if still not fixed - http://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-dns-server-not-responding-on-windows-7

Also, according to most of the comments in the article, if you have McafEE Antivirus installed, that is (99%) the culprit.

Comment: Nope, I have no antivirus installed. And my windows is fresh, like 3-4 days old :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13502/discussion-between-pranav-jituri-and-cengiz-frostclaw)